# Logstash unrecognised countries VM option 'UseParNewGC'

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

I'm not able to import into Kibana using Logstash, I have the following versions on my Mac, please help.

- Logstash 6.5.4
- Kibana 6.5.4
- Elasticsearch 6.5.4
- Java 11.0.1

I receive this error

**Error message**

```
unrecognised countries VM option 'UseParNewGC' 
Error not create the Java virtual machine
Error fatal exception has occurred.  Program will exist.
```

I've created the following config file

**Config file (cars.config)**

```
input {
    file {
        start_position => "beginning"
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
    }
}
filter {
    csv {
        separator => ","
        columns => [ "maker", "model", "mileage", "manufacture_year", "engine_power", "fuel_type", "date_created", "price_eur", "door_count", "seat_count" ]
    }
    mutate {convert => [ "door_count", "integer" ]}
    mutate {convert => [ "seat_count", "integer" ]}
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "localhost"
        index => "cars"
        document_type => "sold_cars"
    }
    stdout {}
}
```

**Command I'm using to import**

```
bin/logstash -f cars.config
```

**Update - after making configuration change**

Have applied configuration changes below, in `jvm.options` file:

```
Remove line: -XX:+UseParNewGC
Remove line: -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
Add: -XX:+UseG1GC
```

**Result/ second attempt**

[console window output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvqpQ.png)

**Update 2**

[Second attempt using full path to config file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIjwo.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Downgrade your system's Java to version 8 or unpack `jdk8` somewhere and in the start-up script `logstash` add `export JAVA_HOME=/PATH_TO_JDK8/`
2. In `jvm.options` file:

   Remove line: `-XX:+UseParNewGC`

   Remove line: `-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC`

   Add: `-XX:+UseG1GC`

For more details about the issue refer to https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/9316

Comment: I've gone for option 2 - I've attached the console window output after re-running the import

Comment: @James Looks like your Logstash is working properly now but there is something wrong with the configuration file. I think that Logstash is trying to read incorrect file, instead of `cars.config` try the full path.